# Change DbContext in ASP.NET Middleware

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, dependency-injection

```cs
public class RequestCultureMiddleware
    {
        private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

        public RequestCultureMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
        {
            _next = next;
        }

        public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context)
        {
            var cultureQuery = context.Request.Query["culture"];
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(cultureQuery))
            {
                var culture = new CultureInfo(cultureQuery);

                CultureInfo.CurrentCulture = culture;
                CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture = culture;

            }

            // Call the next delegate/middleware in the pipeline
            await _next(context);
        }
```

In this example, custom middleware is implemented. I want to change the DbContext depending on what I do in this middleware. I could add a DbContext parameter that would be injected, and do what I need to do with it:

```cs
public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context, MyDbContext context)
{
    context.Database.GetDbConnection().ConnectionString = "..."; // +
    var cultureQuery = context.Request.Query["culture"];
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(cultureQuery))
    {
        var culture = new CultureInfo(cultureQuery);

        CultureInfo.CurrentCulture = culture;
        CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture = culture;

    }

    // Call the next delegate/middleware in the pipeline
    await _next(context);
}
```

However, how would I propagate the new DbContext?

Comment: From Timur Umerov: *Do you need to create a DbContext with specific connection string based on some data in the request? Did I understand that correctly?*

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Yes

Comment: But why would you do that?

Comment: @davidfowl Multi-tenant software

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to register your `DbContext` in `ConfigureServices` like this:

```
services.AddScoped<MyDbContext>(sp=> {
   var httpContextAccessor = sp.GetRequiredService<IHttpContextAccessor>();
   var httpContext = httpContextAccessor.HttpContext;
   
   var request = httpContext.Request;
   // form your connection string here based on data
   // from the request and pass it down to DbContext constructor
   var connString = "..."; 
   return new MyDbContext(connString);
});
```

You also have to add `services.AddHttpContextAccessor()` for that to work properly.